# Ordering a Rails model using an attribute on an associate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails model called Retreat
The Retreat has a has_many association with model Instance, such that Retreat has many instances and instance belongs to a Retreat.

Here's the schema of the two:

```
create_table "instances", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.date "date"
 t.string "venue"
 t.string "schedule"
 t.decimal "price", precision: 8, scale: 2
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer "retreat_id"
 t.index ["retreat_id"], name: "index_instances_on_retreat_id"
end

create_table "retreats", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "title"
 t.string "tagline"
 t.string "type_of"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string "description"
 t.string "schedule"
 t.boolean "available", default: false
end
```

I want to order the Retreat model in terms of the date of the most immediate instance (that is the date of an instance closest to Today). If a Retreat has no instance then it comes last in the order.

How can I do this?

edit #1:

This is how I  finally did it:

```
def Retreat.order_by_upcoming(order='asc')
  if order == 'asc'
    Retreat.find_by_sql("select retreats.* from retreats left outer join \
     (select retreats.title, min(instances.date) as upcoming, 
       count(instances.date) from retreats left outer join instances on 
       retreats.id = instances.retreat_id where 
       instances.date >= '#{Date.today}' group by retreats.title) as s on \
       retreats.title = s.title order by case when s.upcoming is null then 1 
       else 0 end, s.upcoming, retreats.title")
  elsif order == 'desc'
    Retreat.find_by_sql("select retreats.* from retreats left outer join \
      (select retreats.title, min(instances.date) as upcoming, 
       count(instances.date) from retreats left outer join instances on 
       retreats.id = instance s.retreat_id where 
       instances.date >= '#{Date.today}' group by retreats.title) as s on \
       retreats.title = s.title order by s.upcoming desc, retreats.title")
  end
end
```

May be there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
Retreat.joins(:instances).group('retreats.id').order('MAX(in‌​stances.date) desc')
```

Assuming `Retreat` `has_many` `Instance`s

Comment: Instance has a date field. I want retreats ordered by the date field and not by the created_at field. Since, a retreat can have many instances and hence many dates. I want all the retreats ordered by the date closest to Today.

Comment: then use `date` instead of `created_at`, I'll update

Comment: This doesn't work. Retreats don't get ordered at all.

Comment: I see, I thought it was simpler than this, nevermind, try this `Retreat.joins(:instances).group('retreats.id').order('MAX(instances.date) desc')`, this should work